How to solve for angle based on dynamic geometry
I have geometry that has two variable lengths A1 and A2 that represent pistons. They are connected rigidly at the top and bottom with a fixed length of 37. They rotate around a pivot point that is offset from top connection by 5. The pivot point is constrained vertically with the center of the bottom connection (x=0 but y is free to move). A1 and A2 are not parallel.
A1 and A2 are the input, Tilt is the output.
Is it possible to solve for tilt analytically?
Example 1:
A1 = 20
A2 = 10
Solve for Tilt = 15.55


Example 2:
A1 = 25
A2 = 22
Solve for Tilt = 4.65


Example 3:
A1 = 10
A2 = 10
Solve for Tilt = 0



What does "They rotate around a pivot point" mean?

I think it means that there is a rigid connection from the pivot to the middle of the upper side. I also assume that the angle between this connection and the upper side is always $90^\circ$

Let's use some notation: $2L=37$ is the long connection, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the lengths of the pistons, which are tilted at angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ with respect to the horizontal, and $l=5$ is the distance to the pivot from the center of the top. You can calculate the positions of the top of the cylinders:
$$x_1=-L+L_1\cos\theta_1\\y_1=L_1\sin\theta_1\\x_2=L+L_2\cos\theta_2\\y_2=L_2\sin\theta_2$$
Your unknowns are $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. In addition, you don't know the height $y$ of the pivot point. So you need three equations. The first one is the length of the upper connection:
$$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=(2L)^2$$
The second constraint gives you the $y$ coordinate:
$$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2-0\right)^2+\left(\frac{y_1+y_2}2-y\right)^2=l^2$$
When you solve this equation you choose the solution where $y$ is below the upper connection.
You can get a third equation if you consider that $l$ is perpendicular to the upper connection. it means that the slope of the upper connection, multiplied with the slope of $l$ is $-1$.
$$\frac{\frac{y_2+y_1}2-y}{\frac{x_2+x_1}2-0}\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=-1$$
Note that $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ will give you your required slope.

Thanks! I put this through python's numerical solver and it gave the correct values for θ1, θ2 and y as my CAD software. I understand how you got each of the equations as well, but I never took any classes on solving non linear system of equations like this. Its a lot more complex than I thought it would be. I need to implement a solution in JavaScript which doesn't have libraries for non linear solvers. Am I correct to say that its not possible to solve this by isolating each variable and something like Newton-Raphson is needed?

I think you can simplify it a little, by using $a=\cos\theta_1$, so $\sin\theta_1=\sqrt{1-a^2}$, and similar for $\theta_2$. But I think the equations are still non-linear.
